# Finding the values that $ x^2 - 3 y ^ 2 $ can take.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$x \in (-4, -2]$ and $y\in [-1,3)$

- Find the values that $ x^2 - 3y ^ 2 $ can take.

At first, I've written the inequalities

$ -4 \lt x\le 2 $ and $-1 \le y \lt 3$.

However, I don't know how to square these inequalities and combine them. Can you help?

Comment: Does this help a bit? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577602/im-trying-to-find-the-values-that-x2-y2-can-take/2578000#2578000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-4<x\le2\\\implies 0 \le x^2 < 16$

$-1 \le y < 3 \\\implies 0 \le y^2 < 9 \\\implies -27 < -3y^2 \le 0$

$\therefore-27 < x^2 -3y^2 < 16$

---

While squaring, consider the parts of the inequality separately for more clarity. For example-

$-2<x<1$

$-2 < x \implies 0 \le x^2 < 4$

$x<1 \implies 0 \le x^2 < 1$

and take the union of them to get,

$0 \le x^2 < 4$

Answer (score 0):

We have $ -4 \lt x\le 2 $ and $-1 \le y \lt 3$.

Note that the minimum value that $x^2$ or $y^2$ can take is $0$. Then

$ 0 \lt x^2\le 16 $ and $0 \le y^2 \lt 9$

$0 \lt x^2\le 16 $ and $0 \le 3y^2 \lt 27$

and so

$0 \lt x^2\le 16 $ and $-27 \lt 3y^2 \leq 0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It was $x^2$. I had written it wrong

Comment: @Goendo I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Why did it be $0$?

Comment: @Goendo We're looking for the smallest value that $x^2$ can take. We know that a square of a number is always positive, unless the number is zero. Therefore, the smallest value of $x^2$ is zero, since zero was in the range of values that $x$ could take.

Comment: @Goendo Your inequalities don't match. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Are there 36 values that $x^2-3y^2$ then?

Comment: @Goendo There are an infinite amount of values that $x$ could take. But before I say anything impertinent, did you mean that $ -4 \lt x\le -2 $, or that $ -4 \lt x\le 2 $?